# 2д отрисовка фигур

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Появляется лишь черный экран. Никаких фигур.
Загружены `lwjgl.jar`, `lwjgl_util.jar`, `jinput.jar`, а также нативные библиотечки.

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class DisplayExample {
    void run(){
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle("A fresh display");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {     
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL11.glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
                GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
                GL11.glVertex2f(100 + 200, 100);
                GL11.glVertex2f(100 + 200, 100 + 200);
                GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100 + 200);
            GL11.glEnd();
            Display.sync(5);
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            Display.update();
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DisplayExample().run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете взять какой-нибудь древний туториал по отрисовке 1 треугольника (раз уж вы используете `glBegin`) и сверяйтесь с ним, что вы делаете не так, а что не делаете вовсе.

Comment: А почему у вас еще один `glClear` *после* рисования треугольника?

Comment: и где вы выставляете матрицу для `GL_MODELVIEW` ?